# How to send a packed structure in C++ and receive it in C#

Tags: c#, c++, network-programming

I need to write a client in C++, which would send packed structure to the server. Server must be written in C#. I don't understand, how to convert it in C#. May be you will suggest a better way to do this.

For example:

```
typedef struct StudentInfo
{
    char Name[50];
    unsigned int Age;
    char Group[10];
}__attribute__((packed));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specific protocol to use, convert this structure to bytes based on that protocol, send these bytes to server, server can restore these bytes data based on that protocol. That is the common way of Client-Server communication.